# How Does Semiconductor Vacuum Energy Change with Doping?

Tags: energy, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

In the paper ["The application of semiconductors with negative electron affinity surfaces to electron emission devices"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/5/31185/01451556.pdf?casa_token=5fiaPuRrrl4AAAAA:DzD4lSo-MmZ7xyazjOzC3xyOSU2a4QfCru00wMHSzrVTKgyn46uBa5NVhtrDHOwtn3zClPPFDA) negative electron affinity is defined by the condition ($E_c - E_f) > \phi$ where $E_c$ is the bulk conduction band minimum, $E_f$ is the Fermi energy, and $\phi$ is the workfunction.

They state "to maximize the quantity $E_c - E_f$, heavily p-type doped semiconductors are used". I understand how doping changes $E_f$.  What I don't understand is that this seems to imply that $\phi$, the workfunction, doesn't depend on doping.  From my reading it seems like doping will change $E_f$, but not the vacuum energy.  If that's true then choosing highly p-doped materials is pointless because as you increase the left hand side of the inequality you are also increasing the right hand side at the same rate.

Am I misunderstanding how the vacuum energy changes with doping here?

Comment: I am also confused by their formulation. Recognizing that the workfunction can be written $\phi=E_0-E_F$, their inequality reduces to $E_c>E_0$ (which just goes back to the definition) and the difference $E_c-E_0$, called electron affinity, is as far as I know generally insensitive to doping levels. I suppose there's another reason for p-doped materials to be used in their application, and the rest is just a consequence of it, but I am also curious to see the answer.

Comment: As an added remark, it is probably unphysical to have $E_0$ too close to $E_f$, since that would create a sizeable "electron leak"  out of the material at room temperature (low barrier to escape to vaccum)(?) I don't know what is the actual process used to bend the vacuum level below the conduction band, but I suppose it requires a p-doped material in the first place to be at all possible?